# Draw on three.js object realtime using CSS3D Canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js

**Objective:** I have a plane geometry in  scene using three.js. I would like to draw image on plane real-time using mouse click event.User should feel that he drawing on mesh and image is applied at the same location in the scene where he clicked.

I am trying to make a canvas, using CSS3DRender put it into the scene at the same position as mesh and same dimensions. Whatever user draw on the canvas transfer it to plane mesh texture.

**Issue:** canvas is not of the same size as plane ,even when size is specified.It doesn't fit properly to plane mesh. Basically canvas doesn't blend with Plane mesh.

Example:[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7y9ozyj6/202/)

```js
var camera;
var controls;
var scene;
var torus;
var light;
var renderer;
var scene2;
var renderer2;
var div;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  var DPR = (window.devicePixelRatio) ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1;

  //camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 500);

  //controls
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
  controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.8;

  //Scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x15c6ff
  });

  //plane
  plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(500, 500), material1);
  plane.position.set(20, 30, 20);

  //assume i dont know height,widht;
  plane.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  var bbox = plane.geometry.boundingBox;



  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.height = bbox.max.y - bbox.min.y;
  canvas.width = bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x;
  canvas.style.border = '1px blue solid';
  canvas.style.opacity = 0.2; //users should feel like he is drawing on geometry
  var img = new Image();
  THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
  img.src = 'http://s32.postimg.org/rv1t8x33p/tree.jpg';
  img.onload = function() {
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fill();
    context.beginPath();
    var div = new THREE.CSS3DObject(canvas);
    //same position as plane mesh
    div.position.x = plane.position.x;
    div.position.y = plane.position.y;

    div.offsetHeight = 0;
    div.offsetWidth = 0;
    console.log(div);

    canvas.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false)

    function handleClick(e) {

      context.drawImage(img, Math.floor(e.offsetX / (10)) * (10), Math.floor(e.offsetY / (10)) * (10), (100), (100)); //brick

      texture1 = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
      console.log(canvas);
      texture1.needsUpdate = true;
      //material1.map=texture1;
      // material1.needsUpdate = true;

    }
    scene2.add(div);
    scene.add(plane);
  }

  //HemisphereLight
  light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffbf67, 0x15c6ff);
  scene.add(light);

  //WebGL Renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1)
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  //renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 5;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  //CSS3D Scene
  scene2 = new THREE.Scene();

  //CSS3D Renderer
  renderer2 = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
  renderer2.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  //renderer2.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer2.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  renderer2.domElement.style.top = 0;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer2.domElement);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer2.render(scene2, camera);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```